# Unable to run zipkin jar file on Linux server "Armeria server failed to start"

Tags: jar, microservices, executable-jar, zipkin, traceroute

I am new to zipkin server. I am trying to run a zipkin-server-2.12.9-exec on linux server facing the below exception.

2020-03-09 15:36:28.796  WARN 1685 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.linecorp.armeria.server.Server]: Factory method 'armeriaServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Armeria server failed to start
2020-03-09 15:36:28.805  INFO 1685 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-09 15:36:28.806 ERROR 1685 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.linecorp.armeria.server.Server]: Factory method 'armeriaServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Armeria server failed to start

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by:
Open windows task manger and kill all java instances java.exe or javaw.exe